# Google Service Account to User Account

Tags: service-accounts, drive

I created a service account to use Gooogle Drive API's to store and retrieve data in the Drive. I used PyDrive Package to make this process simpler. The problem is the data gets stored in the service account, is there a way to store it in my user account? The service account only offers 15GB storage space, so it would be nice to store it in my User account.

PyDrive can be used to directly same to my user account but it requires a human intervention for authorization. This is not feasible since a cron job is used to store the files.

Any answers are welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use the "user account" storage for regular accounts. In the Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) they mention:

"Typically, an application uses a service account when the application uses Google APIs to work with its own data rather than a user's data. For example, an application that uses Google Cloud Datastore for data persistence would use a service account to authenticate its calls to the Google Cloud Datastore API.

G Suite domain administrators can also grant service accounts domain-wide authority to access user data on behalf of users in the domain."